# how to display image in xlsx file using phpexcel that also display in windows

Tags: windows, image, ubuntu, phpexcel, compatibility

i am trying to display img in xlsx file using code of php
i am using ubuntu. and it is working fine.
but when i open this file in window then all content is there excluding image.
it says excel found unreadable content.
i think there is OS compatibility problem..
how could i do this.. i have to code on ubuntu...i can not code on window

code is -

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$logo = '/var/www/html/power/images/logo.png'; 
// Provide path to your logo file
$objDrawing->setPath($logo);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(600);    // setOffsetX works properly
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(0);  //setOffsetY has no effect
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setHeight(70); // logo height
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0));
```